# Is there an elegant way of checking for nil and assigning to variable at the same time.?

Tags: swift

I feel there might be a better way of doing this in Swift. Any thoughts.?

```
class MyClass { 
        var title: String?    
        init(title: String?) {
        if let tempTitle = title {
            self.title = title!
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just `self.title = title`?

Comment: Your if statement is just adding visual noise and can be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comments above you can just assign to the property directly.

```
class MyClass { 
    var title: String?    
    init(title: String?) {
        self.title = title
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this-

```
if let tempTitle : String = self.title as? String{
}
```

Note: `self.title` has to be an optional type for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to unwrap and use an optional is

```
if let tempTitle = title {
    self.title = tempTitle
}
```

Try avoiding the "!" as much as you can!

However as others said, in this specific case you can just write:

```
self.title = title
```